# Emulating abstract properties on a TypeScript class

Tags: properties, typescript, abstract

TypeScript does not have "abstract" classes as such. But because of structural typing, interfaces are somewhat weak. One cannot for example assert that `x instanceof Y`, when `Y` is an interface.

However I've noticed that a class field that is not initialised in a constructor behaves already somewhat like an abstract property: it appears on the *type* of the class, but it has no runtime presence unless it is actually assigned. This allows the definition of a field in a base class to be "overridden" by a property definition in a subclass, as class `Y` does my example below:

```
class X {
   // behaves somewhat like an abstract property
   i: number
}

class Y extends X {
   _i: number

   constructor () {
      super()
      this._i = 7
   }

   // Provide an "implementation" of i
   get i (): number {
      return this._i
   }

   set i (i: number) {
      this._i = i
   } 
}
```

On the other hand `Z` below makes *use* of the inherited field, by assigning to it:

```
// This sub-class uses the inherited field.
class Z extends X {
   constructor () {
      super()
      this.i = 6
   }
}
```

If I try to use the field on `X` via a `new X`, then the field is undefined. In the case of `Y`, the overriding property is picked up. In the case of `Z`, the inherited definition is used.

```
function testProp (): void {
   var x: X
   x = new X
   console.log(x.i) // undefined
   x = new Y
   console.log(x.i) // 7
   x = new Z
   console.log(x.i) // 6
}
```

Is this a reasonable approach to "abstract properties" in TypeScript? I want to be able to assert things like `x instanceof X` (which precludes using an interface for `X`) and this idiom seems to be working for me so far.

Comment: Typescript [now has abstract classes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2015/09/16/announcing-typescript-1-6.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The place where your solution stops working is when you notice that you can start assigning to the property...

```
var x: X = new X();
x.i = 5;
console.log(x.i);
```

This doesn't look abstact any more.

To prevent this, you could start using code such as this...

```
class Foo {
    get x(): number {
        return undefined;
    }

    set x(val: number) {
        // nothing
    }
}
```

But your base class might start to bloat if you are doing this for a whole bunch of properties.

Comment: Or maybe the `set` could throw an `AbstractMethodError`.

Comment: Yep - but essentially you need to throw errors somewhere - same goes for abstract methods.